# How to get record of today's inserted data in SQL Server in C# windows form application

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I am developing an app in VS2010 c# to fetch a single row data from SQLServer and insert it to MySQL.

In this I have to check that how many records inserted today with one SQL Server query in SQL Server table name RAW_S001T01.

I have tried to Google it but not getting exact answer.
I tried below query

```
SELECT        Date_Time
FROM            RAW_S001T01
WHERE        (Date_Time = { fn CURDATE() })
ORDER BY Date_Time DESC
```

but not getting correct output.

Please help me with correct query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format is your Date_Time column in? If that includes a Time as well (as your naming suggests), you will only find records inserted in the last 3 milliseconds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions got correct answer i.e.

```
SELECT Date_Time FROM RAW_S001T01
WHERE  Date_Time >= CONVERT(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY Date_Time DESC
```

Comment: @Ashok_Karale If you only need today date, you don't have to use `DATEDIFF`. Why don't you just use `WHERE Date_Time = GetDATE()`, as I suggested in my answer ?

Comment: @AlexB you are also correct but something went wrong and I didn't got any result so I just thought that it might be possible by cast and here I got answer that we can cast to the DATE type thus removing the time part of the datetime.

Comment: Ok, don't forget to validate the answer if it helps you :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want records in `RAW_S001T01` where `Date_Time` column is equals to the today date, you can modify your WHERE clause like this :

```
SELECT        Date_Time
FROM          RAW_S001T01
WHERE         Date_Time = CONVERT(date, getdate())
ORDER BY      Date_Time DESC
```

`GETDATE()` is an SQLServer function which will return the today date, like `2013-11-20 14:05:54.943`. Cast it in `DATE` to only keep the date part, ie `2013-11-20`.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your question, you only need to count the number of records added today by the Date_time column. Hope I'm not mistaken. 
Try this;

```
SELECT        Count(Date_Time) as No_Of_records_today
FROM          RAW_S001T01
WHERE        (Date_Time = getdate())
```